# Why is print() not intended for production use, while debugPrint() has no such limitation?

Tags: flutter, dart

It's known (from docs):

> don't invoke `print` in production code, try using a logging framework

```
print(e.toString()); // avoid doing this
```

while for `debugPrint` there is no such limitation

> debugPrint prints a message to the console, which you can access using
> the "flutter" tool's "logs" command ("flutter logs")

```
debugPrint(e.toString()); // it seems OK for dart code analyser
```

How are they fundamentally different, and what is better to use in production - a logging framework or `debugPrint` function and why?

Answer (score 3):

`debugPrint` (or pretty much anything starting with `debug...` in Dart) is not called in production code. Only in (no big surprise here) debug.

So if you want to have logging messages from your production app, you should use a logging framework.